# Which of the following is most limiting factor for data transmission rate?

Tags: digital-communications

Which of the following is most limiting factor for data transmission rate?

1. Attenuation distortion
2. Phase delay
3. Signal distortion
4. Bandwidth

I think its phase delay, but I am not sure. Can someone please explain a bit?

Note: This is not my homework and being a CS grad I don't know details of physical communication.

Comment: Where have you looked? Surely it depends on the magnitude of each factor.

Comment: Thanks for looking into it. I read about different losses related to data transmission in the book "Computer Networks" by Andrew S Tanenbaum fourth edition ,page 125. But the author doesnt mention which of these is most limiting.

Comment: I dont know much but since an attenuated signal can be regained, but if it is out of phase we cant recover it easily.

Comment: It entirely depends, on a physical level phase delay is effectively signal decoherence, if you have high bandwith signals the coherence threshold is much higher for error free recovery. Coherence length is a physical limit for e&m waves of a given frequency propogating in a medium. Even single band AM signals aren't perfect (jitter) and will decohere after a (much longer) length. Effectively phase delay turns your signal into pure noise. On a day to day implementation level the other three are much more relevant.

Comment: Each of them has their limitation on the basis of the medium condition of channel and extent of each cause.Each can be categorized differently for each different condition,may be that's why book doesn't go for ranking, in digital data attenuation distortion leads to  [ISI](https://en.wikipedia.org?title=Intersymbol_interference),bandwith limitation are basically channel based,you find them in [DFT] series(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform),signal loss again occur due to channel,phase delay occur due to medium condition,synchronisation bit are added for that

Comment: Thanks @crasic , btw can you please also tell what signal distortion is...How it different from attenuation distortion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, your question is certainly unclear. But it's still important stuff and valuable information for a lot of visitors (at least I'd imagine), so I'm going to answer it.

The answer is: It utterly and completely depends on what you're talking about. But I can tell you about some tricks to get a feeling for what we mean by data transmission and how the various factors you're talking about come into it.

**How to think about transmission media**

Transmission media can be anything from an electrical conductor to vacuum. All you have to do to get a good feel for what might happen is simply: follow the waves! Start at your transmitter, try to think of how your waveforms look when they exit the transmitter and how the transmission medium and everything around it interacts with it. This goes a very long way in correctly modeling in your head - and eventually in your calculations - where the theoretical limits are going to be.

Also ALWAYS think of information on a transmission line as energy. Information requires, at its core, a minimum amount of energy to be transmitted. You'll be surprised how close theoretical limits and actual practical energy requirements are. More power on either end of your transmission line always means more potential information transfer.

So if we apply this to a couple of common transmission line topologies, we can immediately see what effects are dominant.

**Example 1: Antennae**

An antenna uses nothing as its transmission medium. If we regard two antennae at a distance much larger than the wavelength of the carrier, the transmission medium can essentially be regarded as two very, very loosely coupled sides of a transformer. Loosely coupled because we have geometrical attenuation by design. Your transmitter transmits its power (=information) in all directions, but your receiving antenna is not in all those directions. At least not generally. This is effectively attenuation - and quite a lot. This loss scales as the square of the distance, and you're not going to use antennae for short distances. There's wires for short distances. Antennae are dominated by medium attenuation.

This is even more so for antennae in terrestrial applications, where air, buildings and such things cause even stronger attenuation, as well as reflections and such.

**Example 2: Conductors**

A conductor solves this problem quite nicely. You're constraining your information waves to a very well-defined channel. They can't get out, so no geometrical attenuation.

Well... sort of. Electromagnetic waves in air or vacuum move perfectly; they are not impeded or modified along the way. In a conductor, or any other material for that matter, they get modified constantly. Like light waves through optical media, electrons have a certain speed through conductors which is frequency dependent. This causes the rainbow effects (chromatic abberation) in lenses, and this causes the gradual 'smoothing out' of sharply defined electrical signals as your information flows through the wire. Higher frequencies are damped and phase shifted more than low frequencies.

Also, geometry still matters. If your transmission line has discrete sections that are of the order of the wavelength of your information, it will form an antenna and radiate off some energy. If there are sharp corners, those corners will reflect off some of your wave and either attenuate (through destructive interference) or distort your wave.

**Example 3: Optical media**

In fiber optics, we kind of combine the best of both worlds of conductors and antennae. On the one hand, we get the constrainment (and thus good long-distance performance) of conductors, on the other we get the much better transmission properties of glass versus copper. In glass fiber optics, the medium no longer constrains our transmission speed. Yes, there are some constraints on e.g. the bandwidth of light that glass is transparent to, as well as the index of refraction limiting some aspects of the transmission line, but it's all far from our current engineering limits. It's the transceiver technology that really limits us here. The laser and photodiode receiver technology is simply not fast enough to get close to the THz regime of the carrier frequency in fiber optics. So here the answer is: None of the above. Or maybe, if you want to be picky: the bandwidth of the transmitter/receiver.

**Conclusion**

This doesn't quite answer your question. It's an unanswerable question. But I hope the examples give you some footing on how to approach a proposition like this. I've also deliberately given an example that defies your classification.

(footnote: I'm extremely tired, so please forgive me for spelling mistakes and such)

Answer (score 2):

Given the way the question is worded, the only choice that actually has a direct effect on data throughput is the analog bandwidth, choice D.

At a theoretical level, there are two things that determine how much data you can push through a channel: how fast you can push "symbols" through the channel (its analog bandwidth) and how much data you can pack into a single symbol (the signal-to-noise ratio). The product of these two is the maximum possible data throughput.

Now, choice C, "signal distortion", although a nebulous term, could be construed in some cases to create noise in the channel, so this could affect the number of different symbols you can have, which would also limit the overall data throughput.

Choices A ("attenuation distortion") and B ("phase delay") are effects that can be compensated for, through a process known as "equalization", and so do not directly affect the data throughput of the channel. The channel characteristics can be measured either directly by the use of a training sequence or indirectly by using the data itself in a process known as "adaptive equalization".